# Windows Form Application with Microsoft Access Database Deployment

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

After creating a setup and installing it for my project, I got confused to where is my .accdb file is located. I found out it was located at "C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\WinForm\Winform\Records.accdb". How can I modify the location of my database file to be located at the same folder as my executable file and at the same time to be used as the database? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I modify the location of my database file to be located at the same folder as my executable file

If you want to be able to *update* the database then you really don't want to put it in the same folder as your executable file(s) if they are being deployed to the standard location as described by the `%ProgramFiles%` environment variable (e.g., `C:\Program Files\...`). Users normally do **not** have write access to those folders so attempts to update a database in that location would fail.

Instead, you should consider deploying the database file(s) to a location where users normally *do* have read/write access. For example, you could use the folders defined by either `%USERPROFILE%` (for a specific user), or `%PUBLIC%` (for all users).